# iptables chain INPUT and rule REJECT with own message

Tags: iptables

I would like to add a rule which will reject connections on the end of my `INPUT` chain, but I want to send the following message to the sender: `"Your connection was rejected"`.

How can I do that? Here is my rule without the message:

```
iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT
```

Comment: you may want to consider instead using a default policy on the chain. iptables -P INPUT REJECT it'll match when no other rule matches.

Comment: I know that, but if I add rule with `-A` as my last rule for `INPUT` chain then the result will be the same?

Comment: yea, but it's more error prone that way as any subsequent -A will never match. The one advantage your way is a -F wont lock you out the machine if you're using ssh. I learnt this the hard way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message generated by iptables on rejecting a connection is an ICMP message. There are a limited number of ICMP messages defined in RFC's.

The destination unreachable message (ICMP type 3) is defined in [RFC792](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc792). It has a number of codes associated with it, one of which is Port Unreachable (code 3). The error message in the client is generated by the client itself on receiving the ICMP type and code.

As you can see in this Wireshark dump:[image: tcp reject ICMP wireshark dump]

So no, you can't add your own error messages on the TCP level.